# How do I compute the degree of the composition of two continuous maps?

Tags: continuity, circles, homotopy-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let $f,g:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ be continuous mags with degree $\deg(f), \deg(g)$. Compute the degree of $g\circ f$ in terms of the degrees of $f$ and $g$.

I first denote $$\deg(f)=n, \,\,\,\,\,\deg(g)=m$$ since $f$ and $g$ are conitnuous we know that the y are homotopic to the restrictions of $z\mapsto z^n$, $z\mapsto z^m$ to the unit circle ($S^1\subset \mathbb{C}$). But then I somhow don't see how to procede. How can I think about this homotopy, how does it helps me?

Could someone maybe help me and give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know it yet, maybe but this doesn't help me

Comment: could you maybe give me a hint

Comment: Maybe he already did. Maybe you could read your book and look for theorems concerning homotopies and compositions. Maybe you can look at a specific example and see if maybe he was right about that example. Maybe such an example is sitting right in front of your face.

Comment: @PaulSinclair there’s no need to be so aggressive. If the material is new, it’s reasonable that someone might not see the same “obvious” things that you do.

Comment: @Strandkorb note that $z^m \circ z^n=z^{m\cdot n}$. Have you seen the classification (up to based homotopy) of maps $S^1 \to S^1$ via degree? What’s your definition of degree? There is a different argument you might try depending on how it was defined using functoriality

Comment: @AndresMejia thank you very much for your help. So we know that if $f:C\rightarrow C’$ where C and C’ are circles then $deg(f)=W(f,p’)$ where p’ is the center of C’

Comment: @AndresMejia - I was sarcastic because I perceived a lack of real effort here, but you will note that I still gave good advice on how to move forward. Since the degree of $z^k$ is $k$ (by wrapping number, not just polynomial degree), from that example, it must be that $\deg (f\circ g) = \deg f \cdot \deg g$. What remains is to prove it in general. For that, an application of how homotopies interact with composition would be highly useful. I strongly suspect that such a theorem has been given in the text, and its use is a central point of this exercise.